# Azure Cosmos Database - clone Cosmos Database account without data?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure Cosmos Database with few databases and want to create a copy of the cosmos service account (with the same API / database) as its but without data, how do I achieve this?

clone the cosmos service account." Are you trying to create another Cosmos DB instance

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "clone the cosmos service account." Are you trying to create another Cosmos DB instance with the same API / database names / collection names / assigned throughput values? Maybe something else? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Have updated the question as suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Copy template to here:

[image]

[image]

Deploy the template, and then It will be created:

[image]

[image]

**Original Answer:**

> I have an Azure Cosmos Database with few databases and want to create
> a copy of the cosmos service account (with the same API / database) as
> its but without data, how do I achieve this?

I don’t think there is a ready-made way to do this. Since your COSMOS DB doesn't have a lot of databases, so you can create a new COSMOS DB instance and related databases manually or using code.

Go to this place to get the main information of your COSMOS DB:

[image]

Comment: I could export the template however how do I create the new database using the template exported?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVijayakumar I have updated the answer. You can have a look.

Comment: Correct solution, but so long answer is hard to follow and images will go out of sync. IMHO the tech keyword and link would suffice:
[ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview).